# The Field Is Never Assigned To And Will Always Have Its Default Value null

Tags: c#, null, warnings, default-value, runtime-error

I currently have 2 bool arrays in a class file as defined by

```
public static bool[] bArray;
public static bool[] randomRemove;
```

And I fill `bArray` like this

```
public static void fillArray()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 54; x++)
    {
        bArray[x] = false;
    }
}
```

And I fill `randomRemove` like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
{
    randomRemove[i] = false;
}
```

Where `sizeOfArray` is the length of string array that I use.

I have two warnings for each bool array that says they are never assigned to and will always have its default value of null but I clearly have code that assigns them. Whenever I try to click a button that utilizes the arrays I get a run time error. Is there any reason this is happening?

Comment: Where are you filling them?? the compiler is not seeing any assingment in the declaration and that's why the warning...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call

```
bArray = new bool[sizeOfArray];
```

somewhere in your code before you use them. Also, bool arrays default to all falses.

Comment: No problem, I was able to confirm that bool arrays do fill by default to false. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are not instantiating your arrays - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx for more info.

e.g.

```
public static bool[] bArray = new bool[sizeOfArray];
public static bool[] randomRemove = new bool[sizeOfArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not create instances of the arrays. Try

```
public static bool[] bArray = new bool[54]();
public static bool[] randomRemove = new bool[sizeofarray]();
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the arrays in your constructor or where it makes sense.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static bool[] bArray;

  static MyClass()
  {
    bArray = new bool[54];
  }
}
```

In your code you are only assigning the items in the array which will give you a NullReferenceException because your array = null. You need to initialize the array.